# Possible to set --insecure-registry property in Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use a private third party registry for images.  For testing purposes I would like to add the --insecure-registry property to the Docker daemon inside Elastic Beanstalk.  Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk hides all of the Docker internals.  Is there a way to easily add Docker Daemon properties for Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?